# how to crop and overlay dshow?

Tags: ffmpeg, flux

hello I have a problem with ffmpeg I can't resize my web cam which is 1080p I would like some help please`ffmpeg -y -rtbufsize 100M  -thread_queue_size 9400  -f dshow  -i video="USB Live Camera":audio="Microphone (2- Trust GXT 232 Microphone)"  -thread_queue_size 9400  -f gdigrab -draw_mouse 0  -i desktop -b:v 10M -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -filter_complex "[1:v]pad=height=ih+10:color=black[b]; [b][0:v]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w):main_h-overlay_h[v] -video_size 200x200"  -map "[v]" -map 0:a -c:a aac -r 20 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -crf 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p -fflags nobuffer -f flv rtmp://localhost/hls/stream6`

here is my command line

Answer (score 0):

```
ffmpeg -y -rtbufsize 100M -thread_queue_size 9400 -video_size 320x240 -f dshow -i  video="USB Live Camera":audio="Microphone (2- Trust GXT 232 Microphone)"  -thread_queue_size 9400  -f gdigrab -draw_mouse 0  -i desktop -b:v 10M -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -filter_complex " [1:v]pad=height=ih+10:color=black[b]; [b][0:v]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w):main_h-overlay_h[v]"  -map "[v]" -map 0:a -c:a aac -r 30 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -crf 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p -fflags nobuffer -f flv rtmp://localhost/hls/stream6
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).